# Stuck in low resolution in Mint 17.2 KDE

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, nvidia

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 KDE (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), and following a software update my machine no longer recognizes my monitor and I'm stuck at a low resolution. I have an Nvidia GeForce 650 graphics card.

I've tried regenerating xorg.conf with nvidia-xconfig, but that didn't help. The nvidia-settings utility runs but the only options available in its sidebar menu are Application Profiles and nvidia-settings Configuration. In the console, nvidia-settings raises the error "nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file."

The monitor in question is fairly old and connected with to a DVI port with a DVI-VGA adapter, if that provides any clue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem by purging the Nvidia drivers:
`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
This forced the system to switch to the Nouveau drivers automatically. I then went through the Driver Manager (in the System Settings GUI) and selected the newest Nvidia driver in there. After changes were applied, I restarted the X server (Ctrl+Alt+Backspace) and now all is well.